# Question about solving differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $a(\cdot):I\subseteq\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ a continuous function, and differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt} = a(t)x$. 
I saw a proposition that say:

> Let $A(\cdot)$ a primitve of $a(\cdot)$. Then, $\phi(\cdot):I\to\mathbb{R}$ is a solution for differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt} = a(t)x$ $\iff$ $\exists c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi(t) = ce^{A(t)}, \forall t\in I$.

The implication $\Leftarrow$ is easy to proof.
What I've tried on $\Rightarrow$ implication: 
Suppose that $\phi(\cdot):I\to\mathbb{R}$ is a solution to our differential equation. Then, we have $\phi'(t) = a(t)\phi(t), \forall t\in I$.
Let $I_0 = \{t\in I\,|\,\phi(t)\neq0\}$. Then on $I_0$ we have that $\frac{\phi'(t)}{\phi(t)}=a(t) \Rightarrow \int\frac{\phi'(t)}{\phi(t)}dt=\int a(t)dt \Rightarrow ln(|\phi(t)|) = A(t) + c, c\in\mathbb{R} \Rightarrow \dots \Rightarrow \phi(t)=ce^{A(t)}, c\in\mathbb{R^*}, \forall t\in I_0$.
On $I\setminus I_0$ we have that $\phi(t) = 0 \Rightarrow \phi(t)=0*e^{A(t)}, \forall t\in I\setminus I_0$. Because function $\phi$ is differentiable by hypotesis, then it is continuous and we can "glue" solutions. So, $\phi(t)=\left\{
    \begin{array}{lr}
        c_1e^{A(t)}, c_1\in\mathbb{R^*}, & \forall t\in I_0\\
        c_2e^{A(t)}, c_2=0, & \forall t\in I\setminus I_0
    \end{array}
\right\}$ is the general solution. 
 So the solution is $\phi(t) = ce^{A(t)}$ only if $I_0 = \emptyset$ or $I \setminus I_0 = \emptyset$ 
Am I wrong?
**Edit:**
I think I got it. We have that function $\phi$ is continuous. Then, the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ needs to be the same. So the general formula become $\phi(t) = ce^{A(t)}, c\in\mathbb{R}, t\in I$ 
So.. after edit, am I wrong? Or is a correct proof?

Comment: 'the solution is $\phi(t) = ce^{A(t)}$ only if $x = 0$ or $x \neq 0$' does not make sense. The answer is just $\phi (t)=ce^{A(t))}$ for some constant $c$ (which may be $0$).

Comment: @geetha290krm I've edited. Now it has any logic?

Comment: If $I_0 \neq \emptyset$ and $I \setminus I_0 \neq \emptyset$, then constants from function $\phi$ may be different. One sure is 0, but the other one may not be 0. Am I wrong?

Comment: Any answer please?

Comment: $\frac d {dt }\phi (t)e^{-A(t)}=0$ by product rule so $\phi (t)e^{-A(t)}$ is a constant.